# Axis2 Web Service Client Code Generation Error

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have create an web service sucessfully using Axis2 on top of tomcat. (I'm using IDE as eclipse).

Then I'm trying to create the web service client using the WSDL file the try to generate the Web Service Client codes. It giving the following error

The Error Say File Missing. But I don't know which file need to be added to solve this error.

```
Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.utils.WSDL2JavaGenerator.getAxisService(WSDL2JavaGenerator.java:374)
at org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2.consumption.core.command.Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.execute(Axis2ClientCodegenCommand.java:121)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:254)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1059)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.performFinish(WizardPageManager.java:262)
at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.DynamicWizard.performFinish(DynamicWizard.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:269)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:343)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:159)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.<init>(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:103)
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.<init>(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:214)
... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchema cannot be found by org.apache.ant_1.9.2.v201404171502
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findBaseClass(AntClassLoader.java:1385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1080)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 77 more
```

Comment: Do you have XmlSchema.jar in your classpath?

Comment: Yes. I added to the build path